# Adding custom authorize claim based on local database for Azure user .net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity, asp.net-authorization

I am trying to recognize database user with Azure AD email address, and then add custom claim to azure AD authenticated user, based on property from local database user. In startup.cs I got:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformer, ClaimsTransformer>();
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, KayttajatContext context)
{
    ...
    app.UseClaimsTransformation(async (c) =>
    {
        IClaimsTransformer transformer = c.Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IClaimsTransformer>();
        return await transformer.TransformAsync(c);
    });
    ...
}
```

Then ClaimsTransformer.cs looks like this:

```
namespace Authtest
{
    public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformer
    {

        private readonly KayttajatContext _context;

        public ClaimsTransformer(KayttajatContext dbContext)
        {
            _context = dbContext;
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext ctrans)
        {

          string  sposti = ((ClaimsIdentity)ctrans.Principal.Identity).Name; 
           var user = await _context.Henkilöt.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Sposti == sposti); 

            if (user.Sposti == sposti)
            {
                ((ClaimsIdentity)ctrans.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"));
                ((ClaimsIdentity)ctrans.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
            }
            else
            {
                ((ClaimsIdentity)ctrans.Principal.Identity).AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"));
            }
            return ctrans.Principal;
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at   `if (user.Sposti == sposti)`

If I instead give string value to either one of the variables, if statement works fine. I don't know what I'm doing wrong? Does it have something to do with async? Please help this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Looks like the user object is null. May be because the async firstordefault us not returning in time.

Comment: Yeah that's what I suspect too, how can I ensure it gives a value?

Comment: I am a poor chap in async programming. It would complete blind shot. But you need to first make sure that the db has that email in it. Once that is confirmed then you need to worry about async.

Comment: I am 100% sure it is there, I can do for example: `   if (user.Sposti == "user@emailadress.com") ` and it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to call  string  `sposti = ((ClaimsIdentity)ctrans.Principal.Identity).Name;`  before it was set. Works now, thanks :)